# How to make sure setInterval doesn't stack if it is already running?

Tags: javascript, toggle, setinterval, clearinterval

I have a class with the function `start()` which generates particles after a given interval, but if you call the `start()` function more than once, the `clearInterval()` in the `stop()` function doesn't stop it anymore.

Here is the code:

```js
class ParticleGenerator {
  constructor(pgPhyEngine, x, y, width, height, particleSizeRange = {
    min: 3,
    max: 10
  }, spawnRate = 100, particlesPerSpawn = 1, velXRange = {
    min: -15,
    max: 15
  }, velYRange = {
    min: -15,
    max: 15
  }, particleColorsArray = ["#ff8000", "#808080"]) {
    this.parent = pgPhyEngine;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.particleSizeRange = particleSizeRange;
    this.velXRange = velXRange;
    this.velYRange = velYRange;
    this.particleColors = particleColorsArray;
    this.spawnRate = spawnRate;
    this.spawning = false;
    this.particlesPerSpawn = particlesPerSpawn;
  }

  start() {
    this.spawnManager = setInterval(() => {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.particlesPerSpawn; i++) {
        this.parent.createParticle((this.x - this.width / 2) + (random(0, this.width)), (this.y - this.height / 2) + (random(0, this.height)), random(this.particleSizeRange.min, this.particleSizeRange.max), pickRandomItemFromArray(this.particleColors), true, random(this.velXRange.min, this.velXRange.max), random(this.velYRange.min, this.velYRange.max));
      }
    }, this.spawnRate);
  }

  stop() {
    // This doesn't work if the start() function is called more than once.
    clearInterval(this.spawnManager);
  }
}
```

Comment: clear the interval before setting it so you only ever have one instance running

Comment: `if (!this.spawnManager) {  this.spawnManager = ........}`

Comment: @Pete, thanks for the simple answer.

Comment: `start() { this.stop();`

Comment: @Pete21  Bear in mind if you stop & start as been recommended, this -> `this.parent.createParticle` is still getting called,  so your particles would double up, is this OK?  You could of course cleanup the old particles in your `stop` function, and the doing what epascarello says would work nicely.

Comment: @Keith, I've updated my answer, hope it's proper now, thanks for correcting me

Comment: @Keith, the particles do not double up when I stop and start.

Comment: @Pete21  They will be as that's what your code is doing, but it's likely not an issue as I assume something in parent de-spawns them over time anyway.  It's the reason why I said is it OK.

Comment: @Keith, the parent is a physics engine I created, which has a property named particles, which is an array, so when you create a particle by calling `this.parent.createParticle()` , it is simply adding the new particle to the particles array, which won't double up. And yes, the particles despawn over time.

Comment: @Pete21 `this.parent.createParticle` is getting called again, if that is not a problem, then that's fine.  My initial comment was just to warn you.  Feel free to ignore..

Comment: @Keith, `this.parent.createParticle` is supposed to be called again.

Comment: @Pete21  So that's fine then, why you telling me?. I just said in the previous comment if that wasn't a problem, then that's fine.  I don't know how you particle system works, it might have been an issue, it's not, so that's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize `spawnManager` as null like below,

```
this.spawnManager = null;
```

In your `start` function simply clear the interval first like this,

```
start(){
  if (this.spawnManager) {
    this.stop()
  }
  this.spawnManager = setInterval(() => {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.particlesPerSpawn; i++) {
      this.parent.createParticle((this.x - this.width / 2) + (random(0, this.width)), (this.y - this.height / 2) + (random(0, this.height)), random(this.particleSizeRange.min, this.particleSizeRange.max), pickRandomItemFromArray(this.particleColors), true, random(this.velXRange.min, this.velXRange.max), random(this.velYRange.min, this.velYRange.max));
    }
  }, this.spawnRate);
}

stop() {
  // This doesn't work if the start() function is called more than once.
  clearInterval(this.spawnManager);
}
```